# onDestroy() not firing on device rotation

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm reading **Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide.** The book states that when the device is rotated, an `Activity` is destroyed and a new one is created. The book also has us log the 'on' events like: onStart(), onStop(), onDestroy(), etc...

When I use the emulator on my Mac and press fn + control + f12 to rotate the device, the emulated device rotates, but none of the software does and onDestroy **is not** called.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you know that `onDestroy()` wasn't called?

Comment: The emulator might not completely mimic an actual device behavior.

Comment: @Sajmon I have it set to log when the `onDestroy` method is called.

@edtheprogrammerguy is there a way to mimic a device in landscape mode with the emulator?

Comment: Maybe android:configChanges="orientation" is defined for activity at your manifest. Then activity is not going to be destroyed and created on rotation change.

Comment: I read that book too.  Where are you in it?  It discusses the life-cycle in the first project, QuizActvity.  Later, in CriminalIntent, it discuses using onRetainInstanceState().

Comment: @RickFalck I'm in the QuizActivity chapter. It has you create a different layout for the QuizActivity app, but I can't get it to work without the device rotating and I don't want to move forward without making sure I'm doing this section right.

Comment: What AVD are you using?  Device and API?

Comment: @RickFalck an answer below showed me where it's a bug with the 4.4 image. Downloaded the 4.3 emulator image and it's working. Thanks for the help pointing me in that direction!

Comment: Good to know!  I haven't used API 19 much in my AVDs.  Usually use 8-18.  Now I know there's a bug if I do.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I use the emulator on my Mac and press fn + control + f12 to rotate the device, the emulated device rotates, but none of the software does and onDestroy is not called.

If you are using an Android 4.4 emulator image, that is [a known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671). Try a different image. While the home screen may not change visibly on a screen rotation, other apps should, along with device chrome (e.g., status bar) when displayed in those apps.

Comment: Downloaded the 4.3 emulator image and it's working. Thank you much!

Comment: This kind of bugs are unbelievable... -1 for Google

Comment: Been a year since this answer was posted, and still a problem. Wow!